# How can I make AutoHotKey delete text in a web field?

Tags: windows-xp, script, autohotkey

I've seen a lot of info (here & elsewhere) about things you can get AutoHotkey to do with text once the user has selected it, but is there a way to have an AHK script select the text itself?

I'm writing a script to enter text into web form fields, and I need the script to select any text that's already in the field & delete it.

I've looked at [ControlGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm) but that seems to only work in dialog boxes where you can get the name of the control, which means it doesn't work for web fields. Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the X Y position, you can triple click the field with [MouseClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) to select all text. `MouseClick, left, X, Y, 3`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just send `Ctrl+A`, `Del`?

That is, `Send ^a, {Del}`, in AutoHotkey.

Comment: "!a" is Shift+a. Ctrl+a is "^a".

Comment: `Why not just send Ctrl+A, Del?` Because the question was about Windows XP and XP edit controls did not support `Ctrl+A`.

Comment: What is the comma for? Wouldn't `Send ^a{Delete}` or `Send ^a{Del}` work equally well?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think `Send ^a{Del}` would press all three keys simultaneously, while `Send ^a, {Del}` would press Control+A, release, then press Del (and release).

Answer (score 0):

Alas, cannot post a comment until have a reputation of 50! I was doing it a somewhat long-winded way; position mouse over text, click twice to hightlight, and then send {Del} to empty field (3 commands) For some reason, double clicking on a password field would not delete original, but append to it.

NB: It may not be 100% accurate as when using the editor, it made THAT active, deleted all the script, and then sent the data to that window rather than screen, (and I have Co-ord mode set to screen!) (Thankfully, I have a backup and undo button!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).